# Oracle forms and report 6i compatibility issue

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, compatibility-level

Please advise,is there any compatibility issues with windows server 2008 64 bit and oracle forms and reports 6i?

I am being asked to buy a new server with 32bit processors by my support provider. Are they saying the truth?